# C# string to datetime wrong format output

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, formatting

I'm trying to convert a string into Datetime format this is the my code

```c
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
DateTime endDateDt = DateTime.ParseExact("05-02-2015 15:00", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", culture);
Response.Write(endDateDt);
```

This is the output result

> 2/5/2015 3:00:00 PM

The output I'm looking for should be

> 05-02-2015 15:00

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not formatting the output... That's what you're doing wrong. Please note that a `DateTime` *value* has no format, it is just a value representing a point in time, the format you parsed it from has no bearing on this, it is only used to parse the input string. When you write it back out, either you specify a format, or you get some default format depending on the current culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not formatting string representation of the `DateTime` object. If you haven't specified format then you will get ***default format based on the current culture***.

For getting the desired output you can try this:

```
endDateDt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go more deep..

[`Response.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpResponse.Write(v=vs.110).aspx) method doesn't have an overload for `DateTime`, that's why this calls [`Response.Write(object)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/021tb8dz(v=vs.110).aspx). And here how it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,20e18fa41ebefe91);

```
public virtual void Write(Object value)
{
     if (value != null)
     {
          IFormattable f = value as IFormattable;
          if (f != null)
              Write(f.ToString(null, FormatProvider));
          else
              Write(value.ToString());
     }
}
```

Since `DateTime` implementes `IFormattable` interface, this will generate

```
f.ToString(null, FormatProvider)
```

as a result. And from [`DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx).

> If format is `null` or an empty string (""), [the standard format
>   specifier, "G"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#GeneralDateLongTime), is used.

Looks like your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) is `M/d/yyyy` and [`LongTimePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) is `h:mm:ss tt` and that's why you get `2/5/2015 3:00:00 PM` as a result.

As a solution, you can get string representation of your `DateTime` with `.ToString()` method and supply to use `HttpResponse.Write(String)` overload to get exact representaiton.

```
Response.Write(endDateDt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a more in debt answer. It's appreciated.